# AppCompatDialog: Impossible to change Text Color

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-theme

I am struggling with changing the TEXT color of AppCompat DialogFragments.

My App uses a DARK theme (`Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`), but for dialogs I want a LIGHT theme. I am using Build Tools, Support Library  and compileSdkVersion to 25, shall it matters.

I am able to change everything else on the dialog (title, background, window background) **but not the primary and accented text colors**, that keep on using the (white) settings for the dark theme, resulting in white text over white background.

I've tried dozens of solutions in similar questions here in SO, like:

**1) The easy one: On the styles.xml:**

```
 <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- ignored !!!! -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
    <!-- ignored !!!! -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff0000</item>
    <!-- ignored !!!! -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
    <!-- ignored !!!! -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#F040FF</item>
    <!-- ignored !!!! -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#F040FF</item>

</style>
```

With this solution, the background and buttons style from `AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` IS APPLIED, but not the text colors as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

**2) Manually specifying the style on the AlertDialog Creation:**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View hostView = mHostView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
```

Same problem. Light background, Light text.

**3) Using a ContextWrapper:**

```
    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),  R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
```

Nothing :( Same thing happens

**4) Manually specifying other exotic constants I came across the many posts here in SO, like**

```
Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_Alert
THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
```

This was just a desperate attempt, but anyways the text is not changed

**5) Specifying the style in the fragment rather than on the dialog**

```
    Dialog_Meta newFragment = new Dialog_Meta();
    newFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    newFragment.show(fragmentManager, TAG);
```

I used this solution time ago in a very old API version, can't remember what was the problem, but anyways, doesn't solve the present issue :(

Can anybody tell me what's going on?

Comment: Just to be sure: you're using `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`, not `android.app.AlertDialog`, yeah?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, I'm using v7.app.AlertDialog !

Comment: Oh, OK, I think I see the reason. You're setting your own `View` on the `AlertDialog`, so that theme won't apply to those `View`s. Off the cuff, you might be able to combine #2 and #3, and get the `LayoutInflater.from()` the `ContextThemeWrapper`, instead of `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()`.

Comment: Man !!! Whoa !! It works, and totally makes sense: That was why the dialog part was styled, but not the inside view that was using an inflater from the main activity. I've been fighting with this for 4 hours. Thank you very very much! Please write it as the answer and I'll accept it right away. I'm sure this is going to help more people as inflating a custom view inside a dialog is a common practice and it's easy to use the wrong inflater. Again, thanks :) :) :)

Comment: BTW- is there any way I could then use the solution in (1) -specifying the style in the styles.xml- and get the ( i guess) auto-wrapped context, so I don't need to hardcode the style in the Java part?

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of anything off the top of my head. It'll be a little bit before I get a chance to put an answer together, so I'll give it some thought in the meantime.

Comment: Oh, wait, try setting `android:theme="@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle"` on the root `ViewGroup` of your dialog's layout.

Comment: Yeahh !!!!!!! So simple, so elegant! This is the best solution. Thanks a million, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the custom `View` you're setting on the `AlertDialog`. Though you've set a certain theme for `AlertDialog`s in general, that `View` is being inflated with the `Activity`'s theme, which doesn't have those overridden color attribute values.

There are several ways to solve this.

• Create a `ContextThemeWrapper` around the `Activity`'s `Context` with the custom `R.style`, and obtain the `LayoutInflater.from()` that.

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View hostView = mHostView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
...
```

---

• As discovered by the OP, [rupps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108397/rupps), the `AlertDialog.Builder` will already have the `alertDialogTheme` wrapped on the `Context` it's given, and its `getContext()` method will return the appropriate `ContextThemeWrapper`, which can be used for the Inflater.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(builder.getContext()); // THIS IS THE KEY
View hostView = mHostView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
...
```

From Google's Documentation of `AlertDialog.Builder`'s `getContext()` method:

```
/**
* Returns a {@link Context} with the appropriate theme for dialogs created by this
* Builder.
* Applications should use this Context for obtaining LayoutInflaters for inflating views
* that will be used in the resulting dialogs, as it will cause views to be inflated with
* the correct theme.
*
* @return A Context for built Dialogs.
*/
public Context getContext() {
    ...
```

---

• The theme can be set as the `android:theme` attribute on the root `View` of the `Dialog`'s layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle">
    ...
```

---

• Rather than handling the inflation yourself, the layout's ID can be passed in the `Builder`'s `setView()` call, and it will be inflated with the `alertDialogTheme`.

With this method, however, the `View` objects from the layout won't be available until the `Dialog` is shown. In a `DialogFragment`, this will be in the `onStart()` method.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button).setOnClickListener(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: An interesting side effect of this is that this View's (and its descendents) `getContext()` will return a `ContextThemeWrapper` wrapping the original context. I discovered it because I was casting the context to 'Activity` in some clickhandlers. So in my case I had to use `getBaseContext()` in some places to get the original context.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. You sure you need to use the `Context` from those `View`s? You should have access to `getActivity()` anywhere in your `DialogFragment` class.

Comment: Yes you're right ... Problem is, my dialogfragment is a generic wrapper for views that sometimes are used inside a dialog, but also in normal layouts in the case of bigger screens.  Anyway it's an edge case with an easy solution. Thanks for the tip, though !

Comment: Ah, very good. Didn't even think of that one. It'll already be wrapped for ya. Nice.